# Why does my HTML5 <video> tag work in Chrome, but not in Firefox?

Tags: html, video

I’m using this code in Google Chrome and the video is working well, but in Firefox (version 11) it’s not working.

How can I make it work in Firefox?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<video width="300" height="200" controls="controls">
<source src="http://localhost/javascript/test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't support mp4 as encoding for the video. Have a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements#Browser_compatibility) for a compatibility table.

You would have to provide additional encoding for Firefox to work (like this example taken from MDN as well):

```
<video controls>  
  <source src="somevideo.webm" type="video/webm">  
  <source src="somevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
  I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.  
  <!-- You can embed a Flash player here, to play your mp4 video in older browseres -->  
</video>
```

---

**UPDATE 01/19/2016:**

Now Firefox supports mp4 video formats. So this question should be automatically answered because of update by Firefox browser. Please let us know if your video still does not work.

Comment: I have the same problem. While this thread is old, it seems the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 4, Firefox only supports WebM, VP8 and Vorbis video format. (Firefox 3.5 supports Ogg, Theora and Vorbis.)

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements.
- http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#what-works

You’ll need to create another version of your video in a Firefox supported format, and add another `<source>` element for it.

For an example, see:

- http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#example